# Как сделать цветной текст в python?

Tags: python, color, rgb

Я хочу сделать цветной вывод текста в консоль python, но в большинстве модулей для этой задачи можно использовать только предустановленный список цветов.
Можно ли самому выбрать цвет текста вводом цвета в формате RGB?

Comment: Набор поддерживаемых цветов зависит от используемой вами консоли, подробности читайте в документации к ней же, python тут ни при чём

Comment: Я не про то. В python есть ряд модулей для вывода цветного текста и все они используют заготовленные ими же цвета, а есть ли такой модуль или функции в стандартных модулях которые позволяют назначить как цвет любой цвет RGB?

Answer (score 1):

```
def print_format_table():
    """
    печать таблицы форматирование текста
    """
    for style in range(8):
        for fg in range(30,38):
            s1 = ''
            for bg in range(40,48):
                format = ';'.join([str(style), str(fg), str(bg)])
                s1 += f'\x1b[{format}m {format} \x1b[0m'
            print(s1)
        print('\n')

print_format_table()
```

Comment: извините вы могли бы объяснить этот код ?Пожалуйста